# C function for finding if the two matrices are equal with given tolerance

Tags: c

I have to compare elements of two matrices as follows:

Result1 is a 2*2 matrix i.e

```
           Result1 = 1.1    1.2
                     3.1    3.2
```

Result2 is also a 2*2 matrix i.e

```
          Result2 = 1.11     1.99
                    3.0      9.0
```

If i use if statement to compare these matrices then answer would be dissimilar matrices.But in actual, three elements of matrices result1 and result2 each are closely equal to each other with an accuracy of about 98%, and one element i.e result1[3] is completely differ from the element result2[3].

I am using matrices of size upto 1000*1000 and i want to write a function in C which compares each element of two matrices with an accuracy of 99% and with a tolerance level of +1% or -1%.

My function should report something like this:

> 98% of the elements macthed with 99% of accuracy, so test passed!!

```
     or
```

> 75% of the elements macthed with 99% of accuracy, so test failed!!

Do we have an inbuilt function to achieve this ?
I am using ubuntu 12.04 for this.

Comment: Tell us what you have tried, sir!

Comment: "Do we have an inbuilt function" — no, not likely.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an expected value `a` and a test value `x`, then the relative distance of the test value to the expected value is:

```
rel_diff = (x-a)/a = x/a - 1
```

If you want something symmetric in `a` and `x`, then you could use:

```
rel_diff = abs(a-x)/(a+x)
```

So you can simply use these to check for your desired tolerance with an `if` statement (since the sign of the difference is probably not of interest you only need to consider the absolutes of these).

Comment: Ironically, when `a == x1` exactly, the latter will div-zero-fault. Kind of a bummer for the result of an exact match.

Comment: @WhozCraig only if `a == 0` for the first case or `x == -a` in the second case. But then then `relative tolerance` is not exactly defined anyway. Also the second formula is kind of heuristic and not based on an exact definition.